# Синхронизация диска в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

В `MySQL` есть возможность изменять поведение при `commit` через 
`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`. Например, задание значение 2 собирает все `commit` и сохраняет на диск раз в секунду, а не после каждой транзакции.

Есть ли такая возможность у `PostgreSQL`? Если есть, то как правильно это настроить?

Comment: гугл сказал "Да, такое есть" : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/wal-async-commit.html

Comment: Не помогло, при 10к транзакций в секунду диск нагружен постоянно на 100%, при скорости записи в 2-4 мб/с. С MySQL диск был нагружен на 2-5% и раз в секунду была запись в 20-30 мб.